# what is different between pure class component and regular class component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand when to use React pure component and when 
 to use regular component.
I have this simple questions.

How a component can render different results given same props and same state,any example?

How to define limit of shallow comparison of props objects?
I have not used nested properties in props yet should I always use pure component?

below quote says that also all child component will not re-render when a parent is pure , say we understand and ensured that but does this also mean that we have to wrap childs in pure component or they are fine as regular components?

> Furthermore, React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() skips prop updates for the whole component subtree. Make sure all the children components are also “pure”.

and one last does... this below quote from official docs means we no access to shouldComponentUpdate() in regular components?

> React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison.

Comment: Please do refer the [link](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/). It will help you

Comment: @selmansamet no this is completely different question and not only question but different concept

Comment: @KosalramRamaKrishnan yeah good article but now react  has stateless functions component  and pure stateless functional component ,class component and pure class component and this question is about this things ,not about stateless functional component vs class component

Comment: @yash, sorry, I haven't read enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main types of components in React. Class Components and Functional Components.

Class components are ES6 classes and Functional Components are functions.

The only constraint for a functional component is to accept props as an argument and return valid JSX.

You can use functional components as you like.But when you really need to use component lifecycle methods then you need to refactor it to a class level component.

Please do have a look at this [link](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/)

Comment: *"and return valid JSX."* Nitpick: JSX is *syntax*, not a value. A functional components must return something that is *renderable*. It doesn't matter *how* it was created (i.e. whether you use JSX or not). `return <span>foo</span>;` is as valid as `return React.createElement('span', null, 'foo');` is as valid as `return 'foo';`.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, I agree with you. I welcome editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How a component can render different results given same props and same
>   state,any example?

A component will not render different Result given same props and same state(given you do not use legacy context API). That is the reason, you use PureComponent, because given the same Props and Same state, the component need not go through another render cycle where it compares its props and state and then finally decides to not change anything. That is a waste of computation and hence with PureComponent you stop this comparison from happening by adding another comparison at Props and State level.

> How to define limit of shallow comparison of props objects? I have not
>   used nested properties in props yet should I always use pure
>   component?

If at all your Props are highly nested, then the shallow comparison is might give you false negatives, if the updates aren't performed correctly within the data(objects are not cloned and changed). Shallow compare will perform a one level check for props and state.

The point where you have to decide whether to use `PureComponent` or not comes from an understanding of whether or not, it so happens frequently that your components render method is triggered but no change needs to be made. If the props and state change frequently and only in extremely small cases will the component render with same props and state then you don't need to go for PureComponent since that will add an extra complexity of props and state comparison which would always return `true` for a change.

Making use of Immutable data will aid in shallow comparison checks being fast, since reference change means value change and Immutable data ensures you don't mutate the value directly.

> Does this also mean that we have to wrap childs in pure component or
>   they are fine as regular components

All you need to ensure while creating a PureComponent is to ensure that all its children are also Pure and if the nested components satisfy the above explanation of when to create a PureComponent, then you can write them as a PureComponent itself.

Comment: so we should change a regular component in pure component only if its rendered content is less frequently ( or not) change by change in state or props ,or when chances are that props are alternating , I mean flipping of a Boolean in state or props .

Comment: I am a little confused by your comment. Whether its a statement or a question. 

What I suggested in my answer is that you evaluate whether the cost of comparing props will be lesser then  the cost of rendering or not. If it does, then go ahead with the pure component